# NameError: global name 'PlotDataItem' is not defined

Tags: python, pyqtgraph

I would want to plot the amplitude of an audio signal using pyqtgraph library in python. I'm using PlotDataItem(xValues, yValues) defined here : http://www.pyqtgraph.org/documentation/graphicsItems/plotdataitem.html
So in my code I have created the object "plot" :

```
plot=PlotDataItem()
```

And to plot the x (length) and y (num_data) values i did it like this :

```
plot.PlotDataItem(length, num_data)
```

I get this error :

> NameError: global name 'PlotDataItem' is not defined.

I don't understand why because I thought 'PlotDataItem' was defined in the pyqtgraph library I have imported.
I'm not used to python so i'm not sur of these 2 lines.

Comment: It presumably is, but you can't use any names in Python unless you import them. Please show your imports.

Answer (score 0):

The documentation you linked to says

> Instances of PlotDataItem are usually created by plot() methods such as pyqtgraph.plot() and PlotItem.plot()

So you have to import pyqtgraph and then call plot like this:

```
import pyqtgraph

plot = pyqtgraph.plot(length, num_data)
```

Then use the `plot` object however you like.